# computing integrals in measure theory - iterated integral

Tags: measure-theory

I understand the theory behind integrals in a measure-theoretic setting (i.e. we begin with simple functions and define the integral in terms of them. We can then build up to integrating non-negative measurable functions by taking the supremum over simple functions. Finally we can split into positive and negative parts for other functions).

Unless I'm given an integral that specifically has an indicator function in it so that it is "easy" to compute I just get so confused how to compute the integrals.

For example I came across the following:

$$\int_X \Big(\int_Y f(x,y) \, d\mu_2(y)\Big) \, d\mu_1(x)$$

where $f:X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be

- $1$ if $x=y$
- $-1$ if $y=x+1$
- $0$ otherwise

and the measures are both the counting measure.

I know of Fubini-Tonelli theorems etc, but I get confused how to evaluate this. I can obviously split into cases since the function is piecewise, but i have no idea what to do once I've substituted in the values of $f(x,y)$

The theory makes sense to me, but the application I always struggle with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{Y}f\left(x,y\right)\;d\mu_{2}\left(y\right)=\int_{Y}\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ x\right\} }\left(y\right)-\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ x+1\right\} }\left(y\right)d\mu_{2}\left(y\right)=\mu_{2}\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)-\mu_{2}\left(\left\{ x+1\right\} \right)=1-1=0$$
so that the integral can be calculated by: $$\int_{X}\int_{Y}f\left(x,y\right)\;d\mu_{2}\left(y\right)d\mu_{1}\left(x\right)=\int_{X}0\;d\mu_{1}\left(x\right)=0$$

There might be obstacles here to apply the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem). For that it is demanded that both measures are $\sigma$-finite, which is not the case here if $X$ or $Y$ is uncountable. And there are more demands (have a look at the link).

Comment: I see! That makes sense. So then $\int_{Y}\Big(\int_{X}f(x,y)d\mu_{1}(x)\Big)d\mu_{2}(y)$ can be calculated as: $\int_{X}f(x,y)d\mu_{1}(x) = \int_{X}\mathbf{1}_{y}(x)-\mathbf{1}_{y-1}(x)d\mu_{1}(x)$ then evaluating this. Do you know where I could find other questions to practice? Thank you.

Comment: It is indeed correct to calculate that integral like that and again it will give $0$ as answer. The tricky thing is here that on the other hand the function $f(x,y)$ is not necessarily integrable wrt the product measure $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ because the integrals of $f^+$ and $f^-$ might both take value $+\infty$. Sorry, but I cannot help you with the finding of other questions.